# Does it matter how many imports you have in a single file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am checking out the [AirBnB style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/README.md#modules) on modules but cannot understand if there is any  benefit to keeping imports in a file to a minimum.

To better illustrate... I have an `api.js` file which takes care of many requests. As part of one of those requests is the need to process/resize images before calling a `Model (mvc)` file function to insert data into a database.

I could therefore:

1. Include all `import` statements in the single `api.js` file that deal with image processing or whatever else is required (lets say we end up with some 15+ imports of which only 5 would be used per function)
2. Or I could create a separate file, say `processimages.js`, and `import` just what I need (e.g. ImageMagik or Sharp) into that file to deal with only images to be processed from the `api.js` file.

The first option is neat in that its all in one file, but is it bad practice to have so many imports in one file that are not all used by all functions? The second option separates each of the API's functionality into different files which may be overkill and hard to track.

I am looking for something scalable. This is an application which will deal with a lot of API requests and lots of files - think GoogleDrive/YouTube/Instagram type stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it will not matter, however the latter will be cleaner and will be a lot scalable if there's ton of functions. So separating it in a different file to organize is good decision.

All of those import/require will be loaded upon initialisation of the app. it will also preload the child modules, that is when you import this new files into the main .js file.

Comment: thanks. so do you mean that all imports will be loaded even before they are used?

Comment: yes, you can try using a debugger and breakpoints. those imports might be in a state of 'lazy load'

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 2, and look into tree shaking